# How to override expires header for certain urls in wordpress running on Nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, header

I am running wordpress on Nginx platform and have set expires header on .php and static assets separately. But now the requirement is to add custom expires header to certain urls in wordpress using nginx . I have tried adding in location block but seems it gets overriden by the expires header written in .php block

I have created a wordpress page named sports and want to provide the url with no expiry header and for rest of the urls expires header should be of 10 minutes

My Config for reference :

```
server {
    listen     0.0.0.0:80;                # your server's public IP address
    server_name  www.abc.com;                   # your domain name
    index index.php index.html ;
    root         /srv/www;  # absolute path to your WordPress installation
    set $no_cache 0;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;




 location ~*^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|css|woff|js|rtf|flv|pdf)$ {
                access_log off; log_not_found off; expires 365d;
        }


  location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                 expires       modified +10m;

        }

 location ~ .php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
set $no_cache 0;
add_header    Cache-Control  public;
expires       modified +10m;

}

location ~* /sports
{
    expires -1;
}
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do with in Wordpress using the [send_headers action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/send_headers)?

Comment: Yes it can be done but would be much better on server as it would escape extra php call and development mistake

Comment: IMO this logic belongs into the application instead of the server, but that's just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URIs like `/sports/` are actually routed to `/index.php` with a parameter containing the value of `$request_uri`. Within `nginx` these are *all* processed by the `.php` location block, and use the value of the `expires` directive within that block and that block alone.

One possible solution is to make the value of the `expires` directive a variable:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    expires $expires;
    ...
}
```

And create a `map` of values dependent on the original request URI (`$request_uri`):

```
map $request_uri $expires {
    default off;
    ~^/sports +10m;
}
server {
    ...
}
```

Note that the `map` directive lives in the `http` block or at the same level as the `server` block.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires) for details.

Comment: Tried it . But getting this error : - nginx: [emerg] "expires" directive invalid value in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/abc.com.conf

Comment: Update: Just got to know now , expires directive only support variable if Nginx version is < 1.7.9 . I haven't tried it but it should work. :)